# how to quote the text inside onclick as onclick= " '+var+' " while appending text to div

Tags: javascript

i have written the following code, everything is working fine except onclick variables.

i am getting the error as

> BrowseJsons.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: WTC is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick (BrowseJsons.html:1)
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

code:-

```
var text = '<table><tr><th>Client App name</th><th>Latest Version</th><th>Last Modified</th><th>View or Download</th></tr>';

for(var i=0;i<no_of_rows;i++){
  text += '<tr><td>'+myobj.app_name_array[i]+'</td><td>'+myobj.app_version_array[i]+'</td><td>'+myobj.last_modified_array[i]+'</td><td><input type="button" value="view" onclick="view_clicked('+myobj.app_name_array[i]+')"  ></input>    <input type="button" value="download" onclick="download_clicked()" ></input></td></tr>';
}

text += '</table>'
```

Comment: Try `onclick=\'view_clicked("'+myobj.app_name_array[i]+'")\'`

Comment: onclick="view_clicked(\''+myobj.app_name_array[i]+'\')"

Comment: Thanks a lot Working fine !!!

Comment: LGSon's answer is working....

Comment: Don't try to set handlers in the HTML, that's as bad as `eval` and difficult to manage, as you're seeing. Use proper DOM methods instead.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion , i will try with DOM methods also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape e.g. script in `onclick` handler, by doing something like this

```js
var dummy = 'dummy text';

var text = '<input type="button" value="view" onclick=\'view_clicked("' + dummy + '")\'  ></input>';

document.body.innerHTML = text;

function view_clicked(p){
  console.log(p);
}
```

---

Inline event handlers should preferable be replaced with event listeners

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener